# Authentication headers are not sending JQuery Ajax

Tags: ajax, web-services, jquery, authentication

I have web server hosted in Apache Tomcat 7 with Basic authentication. I have Tomcat user 'tomcat' with role 'tomcat' and password 'tomcat'. Following are my web.xml file and script snippet in client side respectively.

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>testservice</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <description>JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
    <servlet-name>testservice</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testservice</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>testservice</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>tomcat</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>

        <user-data-constraint>
            <!-- transport-guarantee can be CONFIDENTIAL, INTEGRAL, or NONE -->
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>
</web-app>
```

Client script:

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend: function (request)
        {
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic  dG9tY2F0OnRvbWNhdA==");
        },
        url: "http://localhost:1222/testservice/rest/test/users",
        dataType:"jsonp",
        success: function(res) {
            alert(res); 
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    });                    
</script>
```

I'm pretty sure about that there's no problem with Web Service and Basic authentication. But from client script, no authentication headers are sending. I tried `header:("Authorization","Basic  dG9tY2F0OnRvbWNhdA==")` too. But request is sending without authentication headers. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your "success" key is misspelled as "succes" by the way in the ajax call.

Comment: @kuanb, You're correct, but that won't help anyway for this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found that passing authentication via headers is not working with jQuery ajax with jsonp data type. So tried following and works fine.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://tomcat:tomcat@localhost:1222/testservice/rest/test/users",
    dataType:"jsonp",
    success: function(res) {
        alert(res); 
    },
    error: function(err) {
        alert(err);
    }
});  

function callbackMethod(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you changed?

Comment: @kuanb, Passed credential via url. (tomcat as username and password)

Answer (score 4):

Two things to try:

## 1) Add the CORS Filter to your Tomcat configuration

add the [CORS Filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter) to your Tomcat configuration. Note `Access-Control-Allow-Origins` has been purposely left blank below, so no site has access via CORS. But the important parameter that is configured is `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value></param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
    <param-value>10</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

## 2) Modify Your Ajax Call

Modify your `beforeSend` in your ajax call like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function (request)
    {
        request.withCredentials = true;
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic  dG9tY2F0OnRvbWNhdA==");
    },
    url: "http://localhost:1222/testservice/rest/test/users",
    dataType:"jsonp",
    success: function(res) {
        alert(res); 
    },
    error: function(err) {
        alert(err);
    }
});
```

Only other thing I noticed is that your web.xml might also need the following:

```
<security-role>
  <role-name>tomcat</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: From client side request header does not contain the Authorization entry (Inspected the network traffic). While testing in browser it's asking for the credentials.

Comment: Yes, a JS request will behave differently from a browser request.  Are you saying you made the changes above and still no authorization headers are being passed?

Comment: Passing authentication via headers is not working with jQuery ajax with jsonp data type

Comment: Setting request.withCredentials = true; in the beforeSend method did not work for me.
We ended up setting it within the ajax properties more explicitly like so
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }

And this worked.
Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

mccannf got us 99% of the way there with a similar issue hover we switched up how we set the withCredentials property and this worked for us. notice we set the xhrFields property. This can been seen within the jQuery documentation for the ajax method here; http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }, 
    beforeSend: function (request)
    {
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic  dG9tY2F0OnRvbWNhdA==");
    },
    url: "http://localhost:1222/testservice/rest/test/users",
    dataType:"jsonp",
    succes: function(res) {
        alert(ers); 
    },
    error: function(err) {
        alert(err);
    }
});
```

However, we were not using jsonp, simple json.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a solution for this, only a workaround:

Send the Authorization header using two headers, the standard one and a custom one for IE:

```
beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
    if (self._hasAuthInfo()) {
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Authorization", self._makeAuthHeader());
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader("IEAuth", self._makeAuthHeader());
    }
}
```

The server side will check both (the second one only if IE and if the standard one is not present)