# Authentication headers with JQuery and Tomcat

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tomcat, jakarta-ee

My goal is to have a web-service, using an Apache Tomcat 7, and to communicate with it using ajax request from another domain. The web-service is working, but I'm having troubles with the JavaScript part.

My problem is when I'm trying to do any request with basic auth, the headers are removed when the Tomcat give me the request :

```
String basicAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
```

The string is always to null. I've tried to look for answers, and I'm guessing the problem come from my web.xml configuration (and because I'm using cross-domain requests).

The javaScript part looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/Test/endpoint/to/test',
    dataType : 'json',
    beforeSend: function (request) {
        request.withCredentials = true;
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic  " + btoa('test' + ":" + 'test'));
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

And my web.xml file looks like this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <display-name>File Explorer</display-name>
    <description>
        File Explorer
    </description>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>fr.vuzi.controller.FrontController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FrontController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
            <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
            <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
            <param-value>10</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

(I'm using only one endpoint for every request). I've tried pretty much anything I could find, and I don't know if the problem is on the client or server side.

I know there is similar questions: [Authentication headers are not sending JQuery Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889983/authentication-headers-are-not-sending-jquery-ajax) but none of the solutions seems to work for me...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be a typo, but your URL contains "endpoit" instead of "endpoint".

Comment: In Chrome or Firebug, you can inspect the actual XHR that gets sent.  Look there, and see if the Authentication header is being set to what your server expects.

Comment: Yes that was a typo, and not my actual enpoint's name. @McCroskey It seems that my header is not correctly added to the request. Well, actually not added at all because there is no trace of an 'Authorization' header in the request headers...

Comment: To be more precise: When I'm using the 'jsonp' dataType, the request works fine but I can't add custom headers (because of the jsonp), and when I'm doing a non-jsonp request I'm getting an error because the tomcat return a 403, even when I'm trying to configure it to accept any cross-domain request... So I'm guessing I have an issue with my web.xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so that was indeed a tomcat configuration problem, not a JavaScript problem. Here is what worked for me, allowing cross-domain request :

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,authorization,Authorization,accept,Accept</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```